# Getting undefined when database is empty

Tags: javascript, titanium

Im having a problem with my mobile app i do not know how to solve it.
when i push a button that gets data from a database, i parse it in json and when i want to use it in my app i get the undefined. Hoe can i make it so i do not get the undifined.

**Note**
I only get the undefind when the database is empty.

This is the code that i use

```
subjectButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Subjects.getSubjects(url, function(response) {
        if(response == '') {
            alert('There where no subjects found');
        } else {
           subjectView.remove(subjectsLabel);

           var data = JSON.parse(response);

           if(data != 'undefined') {

               var subjectNameButton = [];
               var subjectEditButton = [];
               var subjectDeleteButton = [];
               for(i in data) {
                   id = data[i].id;
                   var subject = data[i].subject;
                   var year = data[i].year;
                   var status = data[i].status;
                   var color;

                   Ti.API.info('id: ' + id);
                   Ti.API.info('type id: '+ typeof id);
```

Can someone explain to me how i can make it so i don't get the undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @0101 said json can't return `undefined` so your problem is somewhere else.
I know this is not the best solution but it seems to work for me:

```
subjectButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Subjects.getSubjects(url, function(response) {
                if(response == '') {
                        alert('There where no subjects found');
                } else {
                     subjectView.remove(subjectsLabel);

                     var data = JSON.parse(response);

                     var subjectNameButton = [];
                     var subjectEditButton = [];
                     var subjectDeleteButton = [];
                     for(i in data) {
                             id = data[i].id;
                             var subject = data[i].subject;
                             var year = data[i].year;
                             var status = data[i].status;
                             var color;

                             Ti.API.info('id: ' + id);
                             if(id != undefined) {
                                    //Your code here
                             } else {
                                     alert('There where no subjects found');
                             }
                        }
                 }
        });
});
```

So here you have a check if one of the variables returns undefined or not. If it isn't `undefined` it will run your code else it will give you / the user an alert message

Answer (score 1):

You will never get `"undefined"` from `JSON.parse`. The error must occurred somewhere else. Try this:

```
Subjects.getSubjects(url, function(response) {
    if(!response) {
        alert('There where no subjects found');
    }
    else {
       subjectView.remove(subjectsLabel); // You probably should move this after JSON.parse

       try {
        var data = JSON.parse(response),
            subjectNameButton = [],
            subjectEditButton = [],
            subjectDeleteButton = [];

           for (i in data) { // Global i?
               id = data[i].id; // Global too?
               var subject = data[i].subject;
               var year = data[i].year;
               var status = data[i].status;
               var color;

               Ti.API.info('id: ' + id);
               Ti.API.info('type id: '+ typeof id);
               // ...
           }
       }
       catch(e) {
            console.log("Invalid JSON")
       };

       // ...
    }
}
```